# Getting map is not a function after pressing back button from a redirected page in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I have page **(MyNotes.js)** that show all the notes specific for that user. So when a button is pressed for detail view the user is redirected to another page **(NoteDetail.js)** where I am passing the id specific of that specific note. In redirect page with help of the id I call an api and populate the data. But now if user presses the back button to the previous page **(MyNotes.js)** I get the below error

```
MyNotes.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: notes.map is not a function
    at MyNotes (MyNotes.js:30:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:17811:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19049:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
```

These are the codes of the pages I mentioned above

**MyNotes.js**

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Noteitem from "../components/NoteItem";
import AuthContext from "../context/AuthContext";
import noteContext from "../context/NotesContext";

const MyNotes = () => {
  const context = useContext(noteContext);
  const { user, authtoken } = useContext(AuthContext);
  const { notes, getNotes } = context;
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      getNotes();
    } else {
      navigate("/login");
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container my-4">
        <h1>Hello {user.name}</h1>
      </div>

      <div className="row my-2">
        <h1>Your Notes</h1>
        <div className="container">
          {notes.length === 0 && "No Notes to display"}
        </div>
        {notes.map((notes) => {
          return <Noteitem key={notes.id} note={notes} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default MyNotes;
```

**NoteItem.js** This is page that contains the function to handle the redirection

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import noteContext from "../context/NotesContext";
import NoteDetail from "../pages/NoteDetail";

const NoteItem = (props) => {
  const { note } = props;
  const { deleteNote } = useContext(noteContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const toDetailPage = () => {
    navigate(`/notedetail/${note.id}`, { state: { id: note.id } });
  };

  return (
    <div className="col-md-3">
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-body">
          <div className="d-flex align-items-center">
            <h5 className="card-title">{note.title}</h5>
            <i
              className="fas fa-trash-alt mx-2 delete"
              onClick={() => {
                deleteNote(note.id);
              }}
            ></i>
            <i className="far fa-edit mx-2 edit"></i>
          </div>
          <p className="card-text"> Tags: {note.tags}</p>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              toDetailPage();
            }}
            className="btn btn-primary"
          >
            Read Note
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NoteItem;
```

**NoteDetail.js**

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import noteContext from "../context/NotesContext";

const NoteDetail = () => {
  const { notes, noteDetail } = useContext(noteContext);

  const location = useLocation();

  const { id } = location.state;

  useEffect(() => {
    noteDetail(id);
    console.log("This is note recieved in NoteDetail.js", notes);
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <p>{notes.id}</p>
      <p> {notes.title} </p>
      <p> {notes.description} </p>
      <p> {notes.tags} </p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NoteDetail;
```

Please suggest me what shuld I do to rectify this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check if notes are not undefined.

```
  {notes && notes.length? notes.map((notes) => {
          return <Noteitem key={notes.id} note={notes} />;
        }) : <p>No notes found!</p>}
```

notes && notes.length are checkinf if notes exist and if it has anything in its array. And then the ternary operator either maps data, or returns no data found

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Can you explain why this was happening because before redirection it output the notes correctly but only gives error when I return back from the redirected page

Comment: I can't tell for sure as I cant see where notes and getNotes are defined, but if initial value of notes is "undefined", "null" or something similar, you must always check if it is an array. Another solution is to define the initial notes as "[]".  It is possible that your notes are an array at one page, but return to some other value once you get back, since context is available to every page.

Answer (score 1):

The optional chaining operator (?.) enables you to read the value of a property located deep within a chain of connected objects without having to check that each reference in the chain is valid.

The ?. operator is like the . chaining operator, except that instead of causing an error if a reference is nullish (null or undefined), the expression short-circuits with a return value of undefined. When used with function calls, it returns undefined if the given function does not exist.

This results in shorter and simpler expressions when accessing chained properties when the possibility exists that a reference may be missing. It can also be helpful while exploring the content of an object when there's no known guarantee as to which properties are required.

Optional chaining cannot be used on a non-declared root object, but can be used with an undefined root object.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyhv1.png)